# Insertar una variable dentro de una cadena de texto en python

Tags: python

Espero se encuentren bien.
Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito añadir un valor(Int) dentro de una String, esto para recorrer algunas url's, estoy usando **python 3**.
Primero me redirecciono en google.com y ahí no hay problema.

El ejemplo de las URL'S a las que necesito acceder posteriormente serian estas:
"http://ejemplo1.com"
"http://ejemplo2.com"
"http://ejemplo(n+1).com"

Al querer redireccionar no me deja, este es mi código:

```
url= "http://ejemplo"
for x in range(1,10)

   nuevaUrl=url+str(x)

   redirect(nuevaUrl)

   time.sleep(1)
```

El argumento de redirection() lo e intentado también de las siguientes formas:

```
redirect("http://ejemplo"+x+".com")
redirect("http://ejemplo",x,".com")
redirect(f"http://ejemplo{x}.com")
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos.